# Converting "Do you have any relatives who used to live there?" to reported speech, is "have" or "had" correct?

Tags: reported-speech

**Context:**
**Person A** found a old paper written in Arabic script  in their basement. They took a picture of it and post it on a language forum.

**Person B** says:
Do you have any relatives who used to live in an Arab country?

**Person A:** I don't think so.

The next comment reads:

**Person B**'s question on whether you **have** relatives who used to live in an Arab country made me wonder if it could be the other way around, meaning perhaps someone who spoke a language that uses/used the Arabic script was living in the house.

Is using the present form of "have" correct here or should it be in the past?

Comment: I tried a large edit. Is this clearer for everyone? I did so because I hear this alot in non- native speakers quite often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Had** relatives is not the best grammar, it implies they are not relatives anymore, even if that was not the intent. Still living or now dead you will always **have** relatives, and **used to** indicates the main subject of the question about Person A's past.

Comment: I think the main reason why the plain _have_ is used is because the verb _do_ only takes a bare infinitive verb as a complement: cf. *"Do you had any relatives" is still ungrammatical whether or not their relatives are still alive.

Comment: @user178049 Correct. Do is present tense and the use of past tense **had** is incorrect. I did not include this because the OP's question seems to focus on a second question that was not formatted as a direct quote asking "DO... , and I was reluctant to edit it into one being unsure of their intent for this.

Comment: @G Warner The conflicting tense is not the problem either. *"Did you had any relatives" is also ungrammatical: _do_ or _did_ requires a bare-infinitival complement.

Comment: @G Warner Thank you. So can I say that "have" here is in present tense because "had relatives" doesn't make sense or should I always use the present tense in this construction of reported speech no matter the verb?

Comment: @Mohammad Yes. But as user178049 explained in more technical terms in their answer. I just explained in a poor fashion.

Answer (score 1):

*Have* is your example is not present tense, but [a bare infinitive](https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive-2/), which is essentially [tenseless](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/non-finite).

The bare infinitive is required because the verb *do* only takes a bare infinitive as a complement. Therefore, both of the sentences below are ungrammatical:

> Do you had any relatives who used to live in an Arab country? 
> Did you had any relatives who used to live in an Arab country?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you talking about the "have" in "do you have any relatives.." or the "have" in bold?

Comment: I'm talking about _Do you have_

Comment: Actually I was wondering about the "have" in bold but thanks to your answer I now know what *bare infinitive* and *tenseless* mean.

Comment: @Mohammad Your question is really confusing from the title.

Comment: Agreed. I tried my best though.